# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native

Have a problem with navigation module in an app. Cannot understand what's wrong, maybe that's my inattention or i know not enough.
This one is NewsRoot.tsx

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NewsScreen } from "./News";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export const NewsRoot = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="News">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="News"
          component={NewsScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: "News",
            headerTintColor: "#fff"}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };
```

This one is for button with link:

```
export const TopScreen = ({ navigation }: any) => {
///...
<Press onPress={() => navigation.navigate("News")}><LCText>To News </LCText></Press>
///...
}
```

When i try to press the button, then nothing happens and console logs error:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"News"} was not handled by any navigator.

Comment: Is `TopScreen` defined in a different navigator?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is the problem about different hierarchy of navigators?